# Opposite of anthropomorphise

Tags: single-word-requests

To anthropomorphise is to ascribe human features to something, such as an animal. Is there a word that means the opposite, namely to deny a feature exists in an animal because it is assumed to be uniquely human?

For example, some would see it as anthropomorphising to say a dog misses its owner. How would you describe it when it is said a dog can not miss its owner as animals do not feel emotions?

Comment: How about misanthropomorphization? ;=P

Comment: @Robusto No, it would clearly be disanthropomorphesis.

Comment: @snumpy: Academicians have argued the point for decades, but in 2004, the disanthropomorphesisian point of view was finally discredited.

Comment: The opposite of anthropomorphise is dehumanise, but that's not what you're after.

Comment: I think your example isn't great, as it's not anthropomorphizing to say a dog misses his owner (they do). Maybe if you said the dog _loves_ his owner... further more, even allowing for that, _not_ ascribing human emotions to non-humans would just be nothing. I'm not doing any of the answers below if I don't ascribe emotion to a frying pan.

Comment: @Sam - I agree that dogs feel doggy versions of emotions. Obviously, their frame of reference is different from a human's but humans will experience emotions differently from each both based upon their individual frames of reference. There are some that will deny that animals have any emotions of any flavour. I was after a word (or phrase) that covers the belief that humans so are special that animals can not share any characteristics.

Comment: E. K. Hornbeck: Oh ho, no! Not for you. No, you'd still be spending your time trying to make sense out of what is laughingly referred to as the "human race." Why don't you take your blinders off? Don't you know the future's already obsolete? You think man still has a noble destiny. Well I tell you he's already started on his backward march to the salt and stupecy from which he came. -- "Inherit the Wind"

Comment: @Robusto Discredited by antidisanthropomorphesisianists, presumably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would think that if you were robbing something of its human characteristics you would be *objectifying* it:

> reduce to object: to reduce somebody, or something that is complex and multifaceted, to the status of a simple object.

Comment: This does not quite capture what I'm after but is reasonably close. Thanks.

Comment: I thought about your comment above where you said "I was after a word (or phrase) that covers the belief that humans so are special that animals cannot share any characteristics." I was half-joking with the "Inherit the Wind" quote I used in the comments of the main question, but there is a bit of truth in that too.  The only people that believe that humans are so special that they can't share characteristics with animals are 'creationists' or 'anti-evolutionists'. This is why I thought about "Inherit the Wind" because the play is about the tension between evolutionists and creationists.

Comment: In terms of feelings emotions, there are some scientists who would also say that animals do not "feel". If something can not be objectively tested and quantified, then it does not provably exist. In which case, Occam's razor comes into play.  Is it that a dog "loves" or it is that humans anthropomorphise a dog's behaviour to match what they understand or desire. Alternatively, does a dog just behave in a way that it has been trained to in order to maximise the returns from its relationship with its owner (or pack). Though, one could say the same about human relationships.

Answer (score 4):

That would be [zoomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoomorphism):

> Zoomorphism is the shaping of something in animal form or terms. Examples include:
>
> - The tendency of viewing human behaviour in terms of the behaviour of animals, analogous to anthropomorphism, which views animal behaviour in human terms
> - Art that imagines humans as animals
> - Art that portrays one species of animal like another species of animal
> - Art that creates patterns using animal imagery, or animal style

Comment: Please can you give an example of how it can be used to "deny a feature exists in an animal because it is assumed to be uniquely human"? I don't quite get how it fits.

Comment: @Matt Ah, you have a point. Zoomorphism is more analogous than it is opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Anthropocentric. That we are distinct and apart and unique, that ego that no animal can be like us. (Nevermind that they get the same diseases, have the same cell structure, much of the same organs, DNA and even neurotransmitters.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).